# org-mode How to link to an rmail message

Tags: org-mode, rmail

I want to link to an rmail message in an org file. I know I use rmail:folder#, but how do I find the folder name and the id # number? There's plenty of information on the Internet telling me that org-mode supports linking to rmail, but I've not found any *real* examples of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Select the message you want to link to, then run `org-store-link`. This is often bound to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> (That's the letter ell). Then, in the `org` document where you want the link to appear, execute `org-insert-link`, which is often bound to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> in `org` mode buffers.

`org` mode handles constructing the appropriate link for you, depending on the mode of the buffer you are in when you run `org-store-link`, so there is no need for you, as the end user, to know how to get the various component parts. However, `org-store-link` does display the link it saves in the minibuffer, so you can see what it's  doing.